# How to create a 2D array in C++ using this specific container

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, constructor, class-template

I'm trying to port a
   `int a[][]`
from Java to C++. I'm using this class as a container [ArrayRef](http://dpaste.com/hold/88601/) for ints because it handles references, and the project uses it extensively. In the AbstractReader class I declared

`const ArrayRef<int> START_END_PATTERN_;

const ArrayRef<int> MIDDLE_PATTERN_;

const ArrayRef<ArrayRef<int> > L_PATTERNS_;

const ArrayRef<ArrayRef<int> > L_AND_G_PATTERNS_;`


and

`static int START_END_PATTERN[];

static int MIDDLE_PATTERN[];

static int L_PATTERNS[10][4];

static int L_AND_G_PATTERNS[20][4];`


Note the trailing underscore to differentiate the two variables.

I'm not sure what to do in order to initialize the two-dimensional ArrayRef. What I'm posting here will segfault because those ArrayRefs are being allocated on the stack. Anybody have a clever way to do this?

The only way I've actually managed to get it to work is using a `ArrayRef< Ref<ArrayRef<int> > >` by making ArrayRef inherit from Counted, which is basically a class that allows for Reference Counting in C++. But in order to access the elements I hen have to do something like *(foo[i])[j], which is slightly nastier than foo[i][j].

```
int AbstractReader::L\_AND\_G_PATTERNS[20][4] = {

 {3, 2, 1, 1}, // 0
 {2, 2, 2, 1}, // 1
 {2, 1, 2, 2}, // 2
 {1, 4, 1, 1}, // 3
 {1, 1, 3, 2}, // 4
 {1, 2, 3, 1}, // 5
 {1, 1, 1, 4}, // 6
 {1, 3, 1, 2}, // 7
 {1, 2, 1, 3}, // 8
 {3, 1, 1, 2},  // 9
 // G patterns

 {1, 1, 2, 3}, // 0
 {1, 2, 2, 2}, // 1
 {2, 2, 1, 2}, // 2
 {1, 1, 4, 1}, // 3
 {2, 3, 1, 1}, // 4
 {1, 3, 2, 1}, // 5
 {4, 1, 1, 1}, // 6
 {2, 1, 3, 1}, // 7
 {3, 1, 2, 1}, // 8
 {2, 1, 1, 3}  // 9
 };

 AbstractReader::AbstractReader() 
 : decodeRowStringBuffer_(ostringstream::app),
 START_END_PATTERN_(START_END_PATTERN, 3),
 MIDDLE_PATTERN_(MIDDLE_PATTERN, 5),
 L_PATTERNS_(10),
 L_AND_G_PATTERNS_(20) {

  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
   if (i < 10) {
    L_PATTERNS_[i] = ArrayRef<int> ((L_PATTERNS[i]), 4);
   }
   ArrayRef<int> lgpattern((L_AND_G_PATTERNS[i]), 4);
   L_AND_G_PATTERNS_[i] = lgpattern;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have should be safe.  The (stack allocated) `ArrayRef`s create heap allocated `Array`s to back them, and then share those `Array`s.

*Edit*:  Thanks for posting `Counted`.  Took a bit of work, but I think I see what's going on.

**Solution**: Don't declare `L_PATTERNS_` or `L_AND_G_PATTERNS_` as `const`.  Alternately, `const_cast` to get the desired `operator[]`.  E.g.

```
const_cast<ArrayRef<ArrayRef<int> > &>(L_PATTERNS_)[i] = ArrayRef<int> ((L_PATTERNS[i]), 4);
```

**Rationale**: 
In `AbstractReader`, you declare:

```
const ArrayRef<ArrayRef<int> > L_PATTERNS_;
```

Then in its constructor, you attempt an assignment:

```
AbstractReader::AbstractReader() :
{
    ...
    L_PATTERNS_[i] = ArrayRef<int> ((L_PATTERNS[i]), 4);
    ...
}
```

Since `L_PATTERNS_` is `const`, `L_PATTERNS_[i]` invokes a method from `ArrayRef<ArrayRef<int> >`:

```
T operator[](size_t i) const { return (*array_)[i]; }
```

This returns a brand new copy of what was at `L_PATTERNS_[i]`.  The assignment then occurs (into a temporary), leaving the original unchanged.  When you later go back to access `L_PATTERNS_[`*xxx*`]`, you're looking at the original, uninitialized value (which is a NULL reference/pointer).  Thus the segfault.

Somewhat surprising is that `ArrayRef` even allows this assignment.  Certainly it breaks the "Principle of Least Surprise".  One would expect the compiler to issue an error.  To make sure that the compiler is more helpful in the future, we need to give a slightly different definition of `ArrayRef`'s `operator[] const` (Array.h:121), such as:

```
const T operator[](size_t i) const { return (*array_)[i]; }
```

or perhaps (with caveats):

```
const T& operator[](size_t i) const { return (*array_)[i]; }
```

After making either change, the compiler disallows allow the assignment.  GCC, for example, reports:

```
error: passing 'const common::ArrayRef<int>' as 'this' argument of 'common::ArrayRef<T>& common::ArrayRef<T>::operator=(const common::ArrayRef<T>&) [with T = int]' discards qualifiers
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but for some reason they segfault if right after that loop I try to access the inner arrays. It gives me a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS or similar

Comment: Yup.  I've got an idea why.  It's a subtle bug in `ArrayRef`

Comment: Managu,

Thanks a lot for your detailed examination and great explanation of the problem. I was wrongly assuming that even though it was a const, if I initialized it in the constructor list and later in the constructor, I would still be able to modify it. What seems strange is that the compiler wouldn't complain about it!

I tried the const_cast, but get the following error:

`error: invalid use of const_cast with type 'common::ArrayRef<common::ArrayRef<int> >', which is not a pointer, reference, nor a pointer-to-data-member type`
I also tried changing the signature to the first version

Comment: but with the following result:
error: passing 'const common::ArrayRef<int>' as 'this' argument of 'common::ArrayRef<T>& common::ArrayRef<T>::operator=(const common::ArrayRef<T>&) [with T = int]' discards qualifiers`
I think the problem here is that even though it is returning a const object, it is going to try to modify it in the assignment, so L_PATTERNS_[i] won't actually get assigned. It seems to me that the only way to do it is by making L_PATTERNS_ non const... Is there a way to cast it to a const later on?

Comment: Doh. Don't have the resources to check it right now, but I think adding a '&' into the `const_cast` will fix my solution.  As to the second error -- that was the intention.  Answer changed to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

Causes may be several. For instance, you don't include in your paste the "Counted" class, and at some point, a->retain() is called (line 130). This method is not shown.